# What kind of background processing is my harddrive doing?

Tags: hard-drive, hardware-failure, toshiba-hard-drive

A bit over a month ago I bought a new Toshiba Internal Harddrive (DT01ACA300, 3GB). It works pretty well, but unfortunately my computer case seems to amplify the access noises. That for itself is not too bad, as they usually occur only sporadically.

My problem is, that from time to time the hard drive goes into a certain processing mode in which it exhibits constant noise. I haven’t figured out how often or long it happens (it occurred yesterday and today, currently running for more than three hours). In any case it is really annoying.

It sounds as if something was constantly accessing the disk, but I’m certain that is not the case.

If I reboot and stay in UEFI setup or grub, the hard drive keeps going (as soon as it has power). During normal usage, it doesn’t feel like the disk is busy, but when I start some deliberately large copy operation, the internal processing will stop for that duration and resume afterwards.

I don’t think it could be a SMART test and in the [SMART output](https://bpaste.net/show/36fee47ad877) I don’t see any errors.

**What could the hard drive be doing?**

I’m afraid the constant work could quickly wear out the hard drive – if it’s not defective already.

Comment: Which operating system? File system indexing enabled?

Comment: @ClassStacker: Gentoo Linux, but as I wrote, it also continues when just in UEFI setup. `iotop` lists `jbd2/dm` and `kworker`.

Comment: Modern hard drives are constantly running various checks and tests, integrity, bad blocks, access speed, cache integrity, etc. during times of no activity on the interface, this is normal in most cases and drives make a varying amount of sound at times when doing this.

Comment: @acejavelin: and I guess one can only get more detailed information with internal vendor software?

Comment: @canaaerus Yes, it is all internal to the drive and not communicated to the host, so only something that communicates to the drive on a lower level would be able to see that information. I would doubt a manufacturer would give that to an end-user.